# Merging branches whose last common ancestor was affected by rebase

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

I have a `master` branch and a `topic` branch which diverged from `master` at some "last common ancestor" commit.

I rewrote history on my master branch using `git rebase`, but forgot, that this included the commit that was the "last common ancestor" with my `topic` branch. In other words, if I now `git log` the `master` branch, it doesn't list the "last common ancestor" commit with `topic` anymore.

I assume the "last common ancestor" commit hasn't been garbage collected yet, since it is still referenced by the `topic` branch. But it isn't part of the `master` branch anymore.

What happens now, if I now try to merge `topic` with `master`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this sort of thing, I find it helps to *draw* the commits.  Of course, since you can't find the exact commit, you'll be stuck with drawing some approximation—but maybe that will help you find the right commits.

> I have a `master` branch and a `topic` branch which diverged from `master` at some "last common ancestor" commit.

So, let's draw that, as a sort of rough sketch:

```
...--c1--c2--c3--c4--m1--...--mn   <-- master
                    \
                     t1--...--tn   <-- topic
```

where the `c` commits are common to both branches, the `m` commits are only on `master`, and the `t` commits are only on `topic`.  Commit `c4` is the last common one.

> I rewrote history on my master branch using `git rebase`, but forgot, that this included the commit that was the "last common ancestor" with my `topic` branch. In other words, if I now `git log` the `master branch`, I can't find the commit ID anymore of the "last common ancestor" commit with `topic`.

Since rebase works by *copying* commits, then moving the branch name to point to the last-copied commit, let's draw that now, using `'` suffixes to show the copied commits:

```
        c2'-c3'-c4'-m1'-...--mn'  <-- master
       /
...--c1--c2--c3--c4--m1--...--mn   [abandoned]
                   \
                    t1--...--tn   <-- topic
```

While you *can* use `git log` on `topic` to find commit `c4`, it's not actually *shared* with `master` any more.

> I assume the "last common ancestor" commit hasn't been garbage collected yet, since it is still referenced by the `topic` branch. But it isn't part of the `master` branch anymore.

That's exactly right: while `m1-...-mn` are "abandoned", `c4` *isn't*.  (Note that the hash IDs of these commits are probably in at least two reflogs: the one for `master`, and the one for `HEAD`.  These reflog entries will keep the commits alive until the reflog entries themselves expire.)

> What happens now, if I now try to merge `topic` with `master`?

The merge operation will find the first actually-common commit, which is now `c1`, and diff the contents of `c1` (its snapshot) with the contents of `mn` (tip of master) to see what you changed on `master`, then diff `c1` with `tn` to see what you changed on `topic`.  It will then combine the two changes and, if that's successful, make a merge commit on its own:

```
        c2'-c3'-c4'-m1'-...--mn'
       /                       \
...--c1--c2--c3--c4             M   <-- master (HEAD)
                   \           /
                    t1--...--tn   <-- topic
```

(The abandoned commits are still in there if they haven't been GC-ed, but they were in the way so I stopped drawing them.)  A `git log` of `master` will now show the duplicated `c4`-and-`c4'` commits, `c3`-and-`c3'`, and so on.

To eliminate them, find `c4` and `c4'` by some process—e.g., manual `git log` and eyeballing, or using `git cherry`, or using `git log --left-right --cherry-mark topic...master`, or whatever you like.  Once you know where `c4` and `c4'` are, you can use the command [Omer suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63207182/1256452):

```
git checkout topic
git rebase --onto master <hash-of-c4>
```

(or even just put `topic` on the end of the `git rebase` command, but I prefer not to do that - it's confusing to start on `master` and end on `topic`...).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you re-base topic on top of the new master using the `--onto` flag. You'll have to specify the point `topic` diverged from master. Find the "last common ancestor", I'll call it `abcd`. Now do this:

`git rebase --onto master abcd`

EDIT: Just realized you said you can't find that commit. That's very weird. Try going to the latest commit on `topic` and then follow the parents until you find that commit. It has to be there somewhere. Try using `git rev-list --parents topic`

Comment: Thanks! Yes, i edited my post to clarify that the commit is not in the `master`'s log anymore. I can still find it in the `topic`'s log

Answer (score 1):

I am sure torek's response will have all the gory details... here's my short answer: find both the new and the old Id of that revision that was the common ancestor.

```
git rebase --onto new-id old-id topic
```

That is to get the branch at the position where it *was*.... but could also run

```
git rebase --onto master old-id topic
```

To put it on top of the new master branch